# Keras: find out the number of layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

Is there a way to get the number of layers (not parameters) in a Keras model?

`model.summary()` is very informative, but it is not straightforward to get the number of layers from it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`model.layers` will give you the list of all layers. The number is consequently `len(model.layers)`

Comment: `len(model.layers)` fails to count "sublayers", that is layers that exist within a model that's acting as a layer in your ubermodel.

Answer (score 0):

To get a graphical view of the layer you can use:
`from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model`
`plot_model(model, to_file='layers_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)`

You will need to  `pip install pydot`
and down load and install `graphviz` from `https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/`
Attached is a
[sample output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoUbw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been a couple of years since this question was asked, today I ran into the same requirement. As @Nickolas mentioned, the given answers do not account for submodels. Here is a recursive function to find the total number of layers in a model, including submodels:

```
def count_layers(model):
   num_layers = len(model.layers)
   for layer in model.layers:
      if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.Model):
         num_layers += count_layers(layer)
   return num_layers
```